# Splunk Routing to different indexes

Tags: splunk

splunkers!

**Problem Statement**

- My logs have INFO, WARNING and DEBUG log entries. The DEBUG log entries have customer-specific information which I wouldn't want to expose to a wider audience.
- I want some specific users in the team to have access to the logs with these DEBUG log entries. Others shouldn't be able to access it.

**My Solution**

- Create 2 indexes. 'index-normal' and 'index-debug'.

  - Have roles and users created so that the access to these indexers is provided accordingly. Easy. Can be managed!
  - At the forwarder, I have 2 segments - each corresponding to indexing the same log to a different index. Note that I am attempting to bypass the props.conf and transforms.conf at the indexer by using  'queue = indexQueue' in one of the sections.

  [monitor:///mypath/abc.log]
  disabled = false
  index = index-normal
  sourcetype = mysourcetype

  [monitor:///mypath/abc.log]
  disabled = false
  index = index-debug
  sourcetype = mysourcetype
  queue = indexQueue
- With the above configuration, I am attempting to index the same file twice and sending them to 2 separate indexes. One (index) going through the props.conf and transforms.conf configs at the indexer and the other (index-debug) bypassing it.
- At the indexer, I am stripping off the logs of log-entries which has the DEBUG string in it.

  props.conf
  [mysourcetype]
  TRANSFORMS-null= setnull
  NO_BINARY_CHECK = 1
  pulldown_type = 1

  transforms.conf:
  [setnull]
  REGEX = DEBUG
  DEST_KEY = queue
  FORMAT = nullQueue

Needless to say, this isn't working.

**Questions**
 - Is this the best way to handle this situation? I am trying to index the same log twice (and maybe thats not happening). Is there a better approach by using some logic at the indexer end?
 - If this is the approach which is to be used, where am I going wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: Do a user who's not allowed to see DEBUG logs need to do searches? If not, you can index all your log in the same index and create a readonly dashboard with no access to the search bar. On this dashboard you will filtrer data with "DEBUG" level on your charts

Comment: Do a user who's not allowed to see DEBUG logs need to do searches? >> Yes

Comment: In this case, I think your solution to index your data in two seperated index is good. Only put your DEBUG in index-debug and then, you make your chart on the two index. I don't know if a user without the "debug" rights do a request on the index will receive error or no result...
If it's an error, no, choice, you have to index the data twice :(

Answer (score 0):

One approach i can think of is to use a search filter

Use only one index and ingest everything in that. Create two roles one for debug one for others. For debug role add a search filter say level!=DEBUG so that it excludes all events in the index with level DEBUG. this will cause the string "level!=DEBUG" to be prepended to all searches run by users belonging to that specific role.

read thru the below

http://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/6.4.1/Security/Addandeditroles#Search_filter_format